# Windows 2008 RunAs

Tags: windows, runas

First I want to excuse myself if I'm using incorrect words, I'm not a sysadmin.
So, from the Administrator's account I want to run a program as another user. I tried "runas" program. It's working quite well but I want, if there's a RDP session using the account as which I'm running the application, the application to appear at the screen visible by the RDP session. I hope that I was clear...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not clear.  You want to log in locally and remotely simultaneously with one account, and launch an app (via runas) on the local account and have it show up on the remote desktop?

Comment: (Also I have to ask...if you're not a sysadmin why are you using a server OS?)

Comment: I want to be logged into the Administrator account locally, in for example Test account logged via RDP. From the Administrator account to run program as Test and I want the program to be shown in the remote session (in the RDP).

Comment: Because I'm a programmer and I'm creating server for Windows 2008.

Comment: @own3r - Thank you for the explanation, that's much more clear.  (I don't know of any way to do this myself).

Comment: Is there a way to log the user Test from the user Administrator. I think about a workaround where I'll create a bat script in Test's Startup directory which is going to start the application which I need...Using Linux is so much easier...starting different instances of the xserver is going to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for remote execution. [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from SysInternals package implements this. It uses this [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429.aspx) function.

Basically what you need is to run something like this:

```
PsExec.exe \\$Hostname -d -s -u $UserName -p $Password $PathToApp [$Arguments]
```

where

- `$Hostname` - name of your server
- `$UserName` - user name of user on which session you want application to appear
- `$Password` - his password
- `-d` stands for "don't wait for exit" - useful for interactive applications with GUI
- `-s` stands for "run application as specified user"
- `$PathToApp` - application you want to run in user's session
- `[$Arguments]` - command line arguments for application; (brackets means it is an optional parameter)